# Mapping flask sqlalchemy models to spring boot entities

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have one python microservice processing data and sending it to the database (postgres).
Another spring boot microservice that is acting as rest api. The spring boot miscroservice retrieves the information from the postgres database and sends it to the frontend.

I'm having trouble with a One to Many relationship.
The python microservice creates the models in the DB on start up and the spring boot microservices just has to use them (no creating or updating).

However, it seems that when I call the controller in spring boot it cant find the releated objects.

Python Models:

```
class Message(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'message'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = Column(String(), unique=False)
    message = Column(String(), unique=False)
    number_of_likes = Column(Integer)
    creation_date = Column(DateTime)
    emojis = db.relationship('Emoji', backref='message', lazy=True)
    group_chat_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('group_chat.id'))

class Emoji(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'emoji'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    users = Column(ARRAY(String), nullable=False)
    number_of_reactions = Column(Integer)
    emoji = Column(String(), unique=False)
    message_id = db.Column(Integer, ForeignKey('message.id'),
        nullable=False)
    group_chat_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('group_chat.id'))
```

Spring boot models:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "numberOfLikes")
    private int numberOfLikes;

    @Column(name = "creationDate")
    private Date creationDate;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Emoji> emojis;

    @Column(name = "groupChatId", nullable = false)
    private long groupChatId;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Emoji")
public class Emoji {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "users")
    private ArrayList<String> users;

    @Column(name = "numberOfReactions")
    private int numberOfReactions;

    @Column(name = "emoji")
    private String emoji;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "message_id", nullable = false)
    private Message message;

    @Column(name = "groupChatId", nullable = false)
    private long groupChatId;
}
```

I call the message controller in spring boot which should return a json representation of the message including the emojis related to the message but I get an error instead.

Error:

```
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_4_, message0_.creation_date as creation2_4_, message0_.group_chat_id as group_ch3_4_, message0_.message as message4_4_, message0_.number_of_likes as number_o5_4_, message0_.username as username6_4_ from message message0_ where message0_.group_chat_id=?
Hibernate: select emojis0_.message_id as message_1_5_0_, emojis0_.emojis_id as emojis_i2_5_0_, emoji1_.id as id1_1_1_, emoji1_.emoji as emoji2_1_1_, emoji1_.group_chat_id as group_ch3_1_1_, emoji1_.message_id as message_6_1_1_, emoji1_.number_of_reactions as number_o4_1_1_, emoji1_.users as users5_1_1_ from message_emojis emojis0_ inner join emoji emoji1_ on emojis0_.emojis_id=emoji1_.id where emojis0_.message_id=?
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
ERROR: relation "message_emojis" does not exist
```

Am I misssing something?
Have I got my models correct?

Comment: your sql query is looking for `message_emojis` table which isn't exist. check your sql definitions.